# Why is the behavior of uninitialized containers different with optimizations?

Tags: c++, c++11

Given is a class with the following element:

```
std::array<Class*, 4> children;
```

In debug mode, checking an element of the uninitialized array on `nullptr` returns `true`.

```
if(children[0]==nullptr)
```

In release mode (with optimizations enabled, regardless whether O1, O3 or Os) however, the check returns `false`.

It seems that the elements are somehow initialized, but accessing them still results in a segmentation fault. To avoid this behavior, I have to explicitly initialize the `std::array` with `nullptr` elements.

```
std::array<Class*, 4> children{{nullptr}};
```

Why is this the case?

*Edit: The compiler used in this case is `Apple LLVM 4.2 (Xcode 4.6.3)`.*

Comment: The actual value of these non-initialized objects are undefined.

Comment: Reading an uninitialized variable is undefined behavior, anything can happen. With optimizations on, your compiler will take the time to take advantage of this. With them off, your compiler doesn't really care.

Comment: Note that `std::array` is an aggregate, which *default-initializes* its members. For pointer members, this means *no initialization is performed* (i.e. no initialization is required, the compiler may do a zero-initialization like in your Debug mode).

Comment: @DietrichEpp: An lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (reading a variable) requires it be initialized: §4.1: "If the object to which the glvalue refers is [...], or if the object is uninitialized, a program
that necessitates this conversion has undefined behavior.". Also, I know it has a technical meaning, that's why I used it.

Comment: @GManNickG :/ you beat me by a second

Comment: @DyP: Sorry. :) Looks like I'm getting a bit slow, since you posted twice in the time I did one.

Comment: "I have to explicitly initialize the std::array with nullptr elements." You can also invoke value-intialization on aggregates using an empty initializer-list: `std::array<Class*, 4> children{};` (or `= {};`). This will also set each member pointer to a null-pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::array` is an *aggregate*, like builtin arrays, so it is not guaranteed to automatically initialize its elements *if they aren't of a user-defined type (elements with a user-defined type are default constructed)*. You cannot rely on the elements having any particular value. In your case, it might be that in debug (non-optimized) mode, it allocates new space from the stack that happens to be already zeroed-out, but with optimizations enabled, the compiler may realize it can reuse space that's not needed anymore, but retains old data.

Comment: It *does* initialize its elements, but it does a *default-initialization* if no initializer is used. This means invoking the default ctor for class type members, but no initialization for non-class type members (like pointers). (And recursive default-initialization for array type members.)

Comment: @DyP Thanks, added a clarification.

Answer (score 2):

In debug mode, the behavior depend on the compiler. Some compiler/debugger set magic values (for e.g. VS uses 0xCDCDCDCD) some uses zero (not good at all). In release mode, memory is not initialized. Thats the reason it may work in debug modus with some compiler, but never in release.

Answer (score 1):

Because the content of uninitialized (that aren't of static storage duration) variables is "indeterminate" - not possible to know what it will be, and can vary from one time to another, depending on any number of factors.

Compiler will generate different code for different optimisation levels, which may cause different layout of variables in memory. If you want to see predictable behaviour then you must initialize the variables. Anything else, and it will depend on any number of factors, including optimisation level, what "result" you get.

Answer (score 0):

Visual may set magic numbers on uninitialized memory. **You can not obvious ly test uninitialized memory anyway**